# How to implement optimized Search in sql server when data is present in multiple tables with millions of rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In my application I need to perform searching on Employees Names,Customer Names etc. consider schema where there is an

- Employees specific table EMPLOYEES ,
- Customer specific table CUSTOMERS,
- Core Table which contains Case Details related to an Employee
- ALL these tables contain 10+million rows

now If a user enters a text in search box I am not aware of whether its customer name or Employee name etc.. now the general approach  would be to search for customers in customers table, employee names in employee table and fetch those Ids and return rows with matching Ids from Core table but this would required joins of tables containing millions of rows how do I overcome this problem.

PS:
Using a FULL text search or using a HASH Table would be on my least priorities.

Comment: A full text index sounds like the right solution if you want to support matches to only part of a name.

Comment: Indexes, indexes and more indexes

Comment: 50 million employees? wow.  write the joins - union them all up.

Comment: I'd use an external searching system, like maybe lucene or a full text catalog or something for that kind of thing, personally.

Comment: With 50 million employees/customers, your company can afford to hire a database guru to "make it work".